# Not able to save application logs to file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a simple spring boot application which produces result on API call.
The application is working as expected but I am not able to print the logs to file.
The logs are showing only in console.
Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project.simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SampleApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#Logging
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.com.project.simple.SampleApplication=INFO

# Logging pattern for the console
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n

# Logging pattern for file
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%

#output to a file
logging.file=/Users/application.log
```

Can someone please let me know if I am missing something?

Comment: Is the application running on Windows? Is `/Users/application.log` an absolute path? Does the JVM have write permission to that location? Here is [the official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging-file-output) in case you want to check you're doing everything according to it

Comment: check file permissions on /Users/application.log

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

> When using **spring-boot starters**, **Logback** is used for logging
>   by default. The default logging level of the Logger is preset to INFO,
>   meaning that TRACE and DEBUG messages are not visible.
>
> Spring Boot has no mandatory logging dependency, except for the
>   **Commons Logging API**, which is typically provided by Spring Framework’s `spring-jcl` module. To use **Logback**, you need to
>   include it and `spring-jcl` on the classpath. The simplest way to do
>   that is through the starters, which all depend on
>   `spring-boot-starter-logging`.

**Custom Log Configuration in spring-boot** **:**
Spring automatically identifies and takes the following files for configuration :
 - logback-spring.xml
 - logback.xml
 - logback-spring.groovy
 - logback.groovy

Or if that doesn't work try configuring spring-boot to have logs written to file only using the following configuraration :
**logback-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

For reference read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html)